# Blob Storage Permament mounting in redhat linux

Tags: linux, azure-blob-storage, redhat, mount, fuse

I have a linux server where i had mounted blog storage but it is temporary mount everytime i restart the machine i have to run this below  command manually

sudo blobfuse /sfp/publicstorage134/blobstorage123 --tmp-path=/mnt/rec/mountpath --config-file=/user1/connection_sf.cfg -o attr_timeout=180 -o entry_timeout=120 -o negative_timeout=180 -o allow_other

How can i make this stoarge mount permanently instead of mounting with this command after every restart. Is it possible to put this in /etc/fstab?

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation is to create a script, such as mount.sh or you can also add blobfuse directly to /etc/fstab

Add the following line to use mount.sh:

```
/<path_to_blobfuse>/mount.sh </path/to/desired/mountpoint> fuse _netdev
```

OR

Add the following line to run without mount.sh:

```
blobfuse /home/azureuser/mntblobfuse fuse delay_connect,defaults,_netdev,--tmp-path=/home/azureuser/tmppath,--config-file=/home/azureuser/connection.cfg,--log-level=LOG_DEBUG,allow_other 0 0
```

Comment: I want to share the same issue that I faced and a detailed solution described on Microsoft forum at the followed link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1351939/how-can-i-get-permanent-blob-container-mount-with